# Dynamic Scatterplot with Cedar

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am looking to attempt to create a web app with the Esri Javascript API that is half map, half scatterplot.  There would be one hosted feature layer in the web map, that has two variables in the attributes.

I would like to mimic some of the functionality that is available with ArcGIS Pro charts:

- Scatterplot will respect what is in the current map extent ([example](http://esri.github.io/cedar/examples/filter-chart-by-map-extent.html))
- If you interact with features in the map, they are highlighted in the scatterplot ([example](http://esri.github.io/cedar/examples/map-to-chart-interaction.html))
- Vice versa of above (select points in scatterplot, selects corresponding features in the map

*Lower Priority Requirements:*

- Draws a trend line through the scatterplot
- Scatterplot will respect the symbology of the hosted feature layer ([example](http://esri.github.io/cedar/examples/scatter-def-url.html))

[image]

I have tried building an app with Cedar, but my Javascript skills are very out of date.  Will try to add a JSFiddle once I have something that actually resembles the above.  Would love a headstart from someone who has more experience with Cedar and the Esri Javascript API.

**UPDATE**

Have made some progress in [an application available here.](http://simonjackson.s3.amazonaws.com/scatter.html)

**Remaining Issues:**

1. Selecting a point on the chart = does not select the corresponding feature
2. Selecting an individual feature in map = does not select point in chart
3. Getting undefined on the chart points.  Suspect fixing this might fix 1 & 2
4. Making the chart respect the colors from the classification served up from the hosted feature service not respected  (nice to have)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. And fortunately, simple answer: Case Sensitivity.

Your layer has attributes `GRID_ID` and `FREQUENCY` but throughout your example you use `grid_id` and `frequency`. I made some changes to your code to fix that issue as well as add map feature (graphic) click to chart highlight.

[Code comparison](https://gist.github.com/ajturner/b86b5e04bd5685e8c9e85e251a9609e9/revisions)

[Working example](http://bl.ocks.org/ajturner/raw/b86b5e04bd5685e8c9e85e251a9609e9/)